# Execute MySQL script from Arduino Yun (without Python)

Tags: python, mysql, process, arduino, arduino-yun

I want to retrieve data from MySQL database which is running directly in Arduino YUN itself.
I want to do it without Python, but directly using MySQL commands and Process. Is it possible? 
Every post that I found in the internet is about to "how to retrieve data using python". But I don't want to use python, because connecting do database and etc. routine slows down my queries.
I'm retrieving data from database multiple times, and from different tables. So I moved logic of data retrieval to MySQL function, and now want to just call this function using Process class. The problem is that it works directly from mysql console, works using python, but doesn't work directly. When I say directly, I mean this:

```
Process process;
process.begin("python");
process.addParameter("/mnt/sda1/arduino/python/read.py");
process.addParameter(msg);
process.run();
```

This code works perfectly and uses python. Inside read.py file I have database call routine. So I want to do the same thing, but without python:

```
Process process;
process.begin("mysql");
process.addParameter("-u root -parduino --database arduino -e \"select process('my_text')\"");
process.run();
```

As you can understand, this code sample doesn't work. But same Mysql script works perfectly, and much faster than using python, if I run it through console.

Comment: @vks can you explain more detailed? or provide some examples?

Comment: @vks Thanks, I figured out and now it works. But unfortunately, this is also slower than calling mysql directly. Can it be configured to work faster?

Comment: which one did you try?

Comment: @vks :) actually there was comment about subprocess. So I tried using subprocess

Comment: @vks Can I call mysql command directly from arduino side, not python?

Comment: @vks Yes, of course. It helped me to solve my problem

Comment: Dont have any idea about arduino :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`Process.runShellCommand`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/YunProcessRunShellCommand). It will accept your complete statement as an argument:

```
Process process;
process.runShellCommand("mysql -u root -parduino --database arduino -e \"select process('my_text')\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess` module.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Using this you can send your mysql commands to the terminal as if sending directly through python script.